# Error en PHP; trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

estoy haciendo una vista para una pagina y me sale lo siguiente:

Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in C:\wamp\www\Curso-PHP\Seccion8-Proyecto-HTML-CSS-PHP-POO-MVC-SQL\views\categoria\ver.php on line 3

este es el codigo pero no encuentro ningun error

```
<?php if (isset($categoria)): ?>
    <h1><?=$categoria->nombre ?></h1>
    <?php if ($productos->num_rows == 0): ?>
        <p>No hay productos para mostrar</p>
    <?php else: ?>

        <?php while($product = $productos->fetch_object()): ?>
          <div class="product">
            <?php if($product->imagen != null): ?>
                <img src="<?=base_url?>uploads/images/<?=$product->imagen?>">
            <?php else: ?>
              <img src="<?=base_url?>assets/img/camiseta.png">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <h2><?=$product->nombre?></h2>
            <p><?=$product->precio?></p>
            <a href="#" class="button">comprar</a>
          </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <h1> La categoria no existe </h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Si le haces un `var_dump` a la variable `$categoria` que obtienes?

Comment: esto es lo que me sale 
C:\wamp\www\Curso-PHP\Seccion8-Proyecto-HTML-CSS-PHP-POO-MVC-SQL\views\categoria\ver.php:3:
object(stdClass)[7]
  public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'nombre' => string 'Manga corta' (length=11)

Comment: Solo te esta retornando un valor cierto?

Comment: eso es correcto